# Delete a row that contains 0 more than 'x' amount of times

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a large comma separated file. I need to filter out rows that contain x amount of columns containing zeroes (excluding the first row). For simplicity, let's say I want to filter out rows with more than 4 zeroes:

```
    gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
    gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
    gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
    gene3,0,0,0,0,6,0,0
```

Would return:

```
    gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
    gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
    gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
```

Filtering out "gene3".

Here's what I've tried (attempting and failing to use ',0' as a delimiter):

```
awk -F',0' 'NF<4 {print}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KISS approach, with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{c = 0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {c += $i == "0" ? 1 : 0}} c <= 3' file.csv
    gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
    gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
    gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
```

With `perl`

```
perl -F, -ne 'print unless (grep { $_ eq "0" } @F) > 3' file.csv
    gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
    gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
    gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk -F',0'`, three copies of `,0` will be taken as three *separators*, giving four *fields* in total. So if you use `awk -F',0' 'NF<5 {print}'` instead, you should see the correct lines in the output.

`,0` will also match strings like `213,0123`, which you may or may not want to take as zero separators.

So, you could also use `,` as the field separator and count the fields that have just only that one zero in them:

```
awk -F, '{z=0; for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) if ($i == 0) z++} z <= 4' file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also solve your problem using regular expressions and `grep`.

```
grep -Ev '(,0(,[^0,]+)*){4,}' file.csv
```

I tested it on this file:

```
gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
gene3,0,0,0,0,6,0,0
gene4,0,0,0,4,6,0,0
gene5,0,1,0,4,6,0,0
```

There are some assumptions:

- no non-zero number starts with a zero,
- zero numbers contain only one zero,
- all numbers are integers.

The regular expression could be extended to address such cases should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the answer is simply

```
awk -F,0 'NF<5' file.csv
```

Use a delimiter of ",0" and where number of fields is less than 5, take the default action which is to print.

I tested it on this file

```
gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
gene3,0,0,0,0,6,0,0
gene4,0,0,0,4,6,0,0
gene5,0,1,0,4,6,0,0
```

Which yielded this result

```
gene,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7
gene1,0,1,5,0,0,4,100
gene2,1,0,0,0,5,210,2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxCoAwEETR3rOMsBsTbawtvYNFEBGioKy3d00WEZtfvIGZrlV1HPqgOscUIQxxkAbiIQHSQrqqLAwCI@QSPJjI1IFNKC@OCc60eY3Qlpr5V/zPgn1@dm/7uWzp0HoAPQ)

Comment: as mentioned in [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447424/72456) that would match something like  `213,0123`

Comment: Yep.  Unsure whether that's a problem here, with the OP's dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If all numbers are integer, then using **GNU** `awk` which supports word boundaries `\<...\>`, you could do

```
gawk 'gsub(/\<0\>/, "0") <5' infile
```

Comment: +1, Given that `\>` is only valid for GNU awk (you may make a note about that) you can simplify to `awk 'gsub(/\<0\>/,"0")<=4' infile`.

Comment: @isaac, note that busybox `awk` also supports `\<`. Also `\b`, though you'd need to write it `gsub("\\b0\\b", "0")`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, busybox awk also have `\<`, `\>` and `\b` (as gawk). But please note: … 1. That `\b` means **Backspace.** in gawk, not "word boundary". …2. That ["word boundary" is coded as `\y` in gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html). … 3. That `/…/` leads to simpler regexes (no double `\\` required), … 4. that in both `busybox awk` and `gawk` this: `awk 'gsub(/\<0\>/, "0") <5' infile` work correctly, and …5. that `\b` only works in busybox awk as a string (not as a regex inside `/…/`). So: `/…/` is shorter and `\<` `\>` are more portable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following:

¶  split records on a comma

```
  perl -F'/,(?=0,|0$)/' -lane 'print if $#F < 4' csv.file 

° split on those commas to the right of whom we see either a 0, or a 0 at the end.

° the array formed by splitting up the record ($_) is (@F) and whose last index ($#) will have how many such commas were there.
```

¶  sed based

```
 sed -ne '
     h;1b print
     s/,/,,/g;s/$/,/;t reset
     :reset;s/,0,/&/4;t
     :print;g;p
 '  csv.file

°  we double the commas as this involves overlapping matches. Also provide a comma at the end for uniform matching. 
 ° a dummy t command is run first to clear the test flag, OTW the actual t command that follows misfires.
° a s/// command is run to do a fourth substitution. If it succeeds => there are at least four pure zero fields. We don't want this so the labelless t command shall take the conrol to end of any further processing. The -n sed option will prevent it from being printed.
° now when the substitution failed => there were three or less such pure zero fields and we want such lines.
° before making changes we had stored the original unmodified line in hold space so we get it back and print it.
```